# Union results from multiple tables which are being assigned dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Table names should be passed as parameter (array of strings). I need to get from each table values of same columns `foreign_key_id` and `updated_at`, but only most recent ten results (by that I mean those which were last updated). I need to union result from each table. Also, I already have list of `foreign_key_id`s for which I am searching the tables. The way I have tried doing this:

```
$foreign_key_ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
$tables = ['table_A', 'table_B', 'table_C'];

foreach ($foreign_key_ids as $foreign_key_id)
{
    $index = 0;

    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $query = DB
             ::table($table)
             ->select('foreign_key_id', 'updated_at')
             ->where('foreign_key_id', $foreign_key_id)
             ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
             ->limit(10);

        if ($index == 0)
        {
            $single_table = $query;
        }
        else
        {
            $single_table->union($query);
        }

        $index++;
    }

        $full_result[] = $single_table;
    }

    $final_result = [];

    foreach($full_result as $single_result)
    {
        $final_result->union($single_result);
    }

    $final_result = $final_result->get();
}
```

But I am getting an exception `Call to a member function union() on array`
 and not sure why, cause `$single_result` in last `foreach` is not array, it's instance of `builder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and not sure why, cause `$single_result` in last `foreach` is not `array`, it's instance of `Builder`.

Given the question doens't specify which in line the error is thrown, I'll assume is in this two lines:

```
// ...

$final_result = []; // <----------- (1)

foreach($full_result as $single_result)
{
    $final_result->union($single_result);  // <----------- (2)
}

// ...
```

As you can see, `$final_result` is initialized as an `array` (1) and then you are calling the `->union()` method on this `array` (2). This is why the error is thrown (or at least another error will be thrown).

Try this instead:

```
// ...

$final_result = collect(); // <-----------

foreach($full_result as $single_result)
{
    $final_result = $final_result->union($single_result);  // <-----------
}

// ...
```

Comment: Exactly! I was looking at it's elements, but they weren't the problem, but the array itself. Didn't know that, thank you very much.

Comment: I have one question outside this topic: You have edited my question, moving brackets to new line while they were at the same line as function definition. Is that some codex `php` should be written like? On my job I am coding in `JS` and `PHP` and in both languages I am writing brackets inline instead of newline.

Comment: It is just a code styling preference. I (try to) follow [this guide](https://guidelines.spatie.be/code-style/laravel-phpto) to improve code readability and standardize my code, check it out [here](https://guidelines.spatie.be/code-style/laravel-php).